# Groovy SQL and Array parameter

Tags: arrays, stored-procedures, jdbc, groovy, connection

I have a stored procedure which accepts a parameter of type `Array` and I'd like to invoke it via `groovy.sql.Sql.call(...)` but I can't figure out how to instantiate a `java.sql.Array` instance to pass as a parameter.

In normal JDBC, I can create a `java.sql.Array` via `java.sql.Connection.createArrayOf(...)` but I can't get a reference to the connection through `groovy.sql.Sql`.

Note, I have created my Sql instance by passing a DataSource so `groovy.sql.Sql.getConnection()` returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `groovy.sql.Sql` class will create a connection on demand from the DataSource and throw it away when it's done.  Use `cacheConnection` to keep the connection around for you to use:

```
def sql = new Sql(datasource)
sql.cacheConnection {
    assert sql.connection != null
    println sql.rows('select * from mytable where arraycol = ?',
        sql.connection.createArrayOf('integer', [1, 2, 3] as Object[]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ataylor. Using your answer as a guide, I found that the connection is passed into the closure so you don't need to reference sql.getConnection(). I came up with the following which I prefer:

```
def sql = new Sql(datasource)
sql.cacheConnection { Connection con ->
    assert con != null
    def array = con.createArrayOf('integer', [1, 2, 3] as Object[]))
    println sql.rows('select * from mytable where arraycol = ?', array)
}
```